# SharePoint Library Tree View for Outlok Addin

Tags: c#, sharepoint, tree, treeview, save

I am currently developing an Outlook Addin, this is my first time doing something Object oriented,
I'm a beginner, but since you all must have been there at somepoint i think you can all be **compassionate** with me :) and not judge me if the way I ask might come across as stupid.

I have an Outlook Addin, which saves e-mails from Outlook to SharePoint, what i Need is a **SharePoint Library Tree View** which Shows up once the *Save To SharePoint* button is pressed (Should look something like this [TreeView](http://images.bilsimser.com/SharePointSolutionTree.png))

**My Question** does anybody here have any experience with this, has anybody done anything similiar, can anybody help me get a headstart through any tipps?
I Thank you all in Advance, and am looking Forward to your **Great** Answers.

what i have so far is this, but i Need some tipps on how to use it:

```
public class WebPart1 : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
{

TreeView treeView;
TreeNode rootNode;

public WebPart1()
{
}

protected override void RenderContents(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // render the control
    base.RenderContents(writer);
}

protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();

    // get the current site
    SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
    using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        // set the tree view properties
        treeView = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView();
        treeView.ShowLines = true; // show lines
        treeView.ExpandDepth = 0; // expand non

        SPList list = currentWeb.Lists["All Programs"];

        // build the tree
        rootNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode(list.Title, "", 
                   "", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString(), "");

        // loop down the tree
        GetFolder(list.RootFolder, rootNode, list);

        // add the root node to tree view
        treeView.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
    }
    this.Controls.Add(treeView);
    base.CreateChildControls();
}

public void GetFolder(SPFolder folder, TreeNode rootNode, SPList list)
{
    // create a new node
    TreeNode newNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode(folder.Name, "", 
                       "~/_layouts/images/itdl.gif", 
                       folder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString(), "");
    try
    {
        // don't add the forms folder
        if (folder.Name != "Link")
        {
            // loop through all child folders
            foreach (SPFolder childFolder in folder.SubFolders)
            {
                // don't add the forms folder
                if (childFolder.Name != "Link")
                {
                    TreeNode trn = 
                      new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode(childFolder.Name, "", 
                      "", childFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString(), "");
                    newNode = GetItems(childFolder, trn);

                    // add the new node to the tree
                    rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}

public TreeNode GetItems(SPFolder folder, TreeNode node)
{
    //Get Items from childFolder
    SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
    qry.Folder = folder;
    SPWeb web = null;

    web = folder.ParentWeb;
    SPListItemCollection ic = web.Lists[folder.ParentListId].GetItems(qry);

    foreach (SPListItem subitem in ic)
    {
        if (subitem.Folder != null) //Is Subfolder
        {
            // create a new node for a subfolder and add items to it
            TreeNode childNode = 
              new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode(subitem.Folder.Name);
            node.ChildNodes.Add(GetItems(subitem.Folder, childNode));
        }  

        if (subitem.Folder == null)
        {
            TreeNode trn1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode(
                                  subitem["Title0"].ToString());
            node.ChildNodes.Add(trn1);
        }
    }
    return node;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the object orientation, you need to understand that there are classes and objects which are instances of a class.

A class is just a generic blueprint. 
An object is an instantiation of that blueprint.

The parameters you set withing the class can be accessed by an object using the dot operator.

For example if you had a class called Person, with an age parameter. If you instantiated the class creating an object called Tim, you could say. Tim.age to refer to the age property.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer,
sadly what I'm looking for is tipps on SharePoint Tree View

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37530/Document-Library-Tree-View-Web-Part-for-SharePoint

Comment: tried it,seems uninstallable
when i open the Source code Visual Studio 2012 says Incompatible

Comment: sorry I'm not able to help any further, btw it is convention to choose an answer on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an application that does exactly what you describe: 
https://out2share.codeplex.com/
You can look at the code.